# Understanding the directory structure / modules which gets created in EJB 3.x

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.1

I have created a simple EJB 3.1 project using eclipse IDE, and below is the layout of the project:

[image]

I created a simple Session Bean (stateless) and the above is the directory structure.

I have read books (to the extend needed) on EJB 3.x, but no where there is any mention of all this directory structure.

Can anyone help me understand the logical relation of these directory structure and how can I learn it in an easy-to-understand without cramming the things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get with Eclipse is the structure that suits Eclipse. If you create the same with Netbeans or IntelliJ you will likely get another directory structure, or if you use Maven you get another (customizable) structure.

What is important is the final build. If you export your project in Eclipse you will get the standard deployable structure conform to JEE specification.

To reassume, each vendor (Eclipse, Netbeans...etc) has its own way to arrange things and it is detailed in the corresponding manual. But every vendor must adhere to specifications when producing the final build.

Then few things about your screenshot:

**FirstEJBProj**

where your EJBs reside, ejbModule is where Eclipse keep source code (Java file).

**FirstEJBProjClient**

here you will find the business interfaces implemented by the EJBs, that you can pack and distribute to your client, remote or local. Again ejbModule is where all your classes are. Also, I don't know why Eclipse creates it as an EJB project, a Jar would be enough.

**FirstEJBProjEar**

Just the ear container that gather all.

Am I answered your question ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped to clear the doubt. One more thing as you mentioned that the directory layout is what suits to each IDE; so the way Netbeans will display would be different from what Eclipse does. Where can I get more info, say for specific IDE e.g. Eclipse, which section of the guide I need to refer to?

Comment: You have to refer to the online help of each products, don't know where exactly, but I am pretty sure there is a specific section. If I am not wrong, eclipse wizard asks you where you want to have things, directory etc.